# Specify some variables in one document to affect other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script what write some texts, and I don't want the user open this long script just for change some texts.

For this, I want to put some variables in my index.html document to affect changes in my javascript document.

**Example:**

```
// index.html 

<script type="text/javascript">
  var name = "put here your name"; // Your name.
</script>
```

I want to receive the content of the variable name in my .js script.

How i do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript variables are generally assigned globally to the `windows` property. Therefore, you can access `name` in another document just by typing `name`.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NsBPPe5SYIoYRwO9SfHE

Comment: Hm, thanks for the help, but is not that what i need. What i need is pass the variable in index.html to the script.js, not otherwise.

Comment: I got you wrong. I don't quite understand which file should do what.

Comment: Hm, you have seen that plugins if we can edit some properties like this:

$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'random',               // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices: 15,